# Error NU1202 Package System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I created a default Mobile App (Xamarin Forms) with Master-detail template, in Visual studio 2019 Community Edition Version Version 16.5.4 on Windows

And on creation itself, this package error popped up for the .
Uninstalling or removing the package is not useful, since package restore failure does not allow adding it back.

Error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
  - uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) MyApp2  C:\Users...\MyApp2\MyApp2\MyApp2\MyApp2.csproj 1

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: While it may (or may not) be implied what you're attempting to resolve, it may be wise to edit your question to actually include a question.

Comment: @Andrew there you go

Comment: @sum1 You said that you create Xamarin.Forms app with Master-Detail template, then you have this problem with error message? I don't have this error message when create Master-detail Forms app. Or you have this error message when you try to install System.Numerics.Vectors dll?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, so when I created the Master-detail Forms app, the packages section by default has System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 package, which seems to be incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0

Comment: @sum1 I create Xamarin.forms with Master-detail template, and there is not System.Numerics.Vectors installed in nuget package, and I install System.Numerics.Vectors dll by nuget package, there is no error message, I use Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019.